# Подсчет количества повторяющихся сообщений в таблице

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

Нужно подсчитать для механизма сколько каких аварий у него было за период времени
Делая такой запрос:

```
SELECT MsgNr, PValue3, PText5, Text1
FROM [NEZHELSKYI-PC_HMI#3F9P_ALG_202206270821_202207061302].[dbo].[AlgViewExRUS_ID_OPT] 
WHERE (Class = 64 OR (Class = 65 AND MsgNr = 210)) AND TimeDiff <> 0 AND DateTime >= '2022-06-30' AND DateTime <= '2022-08-06'
ORDER BY PValue3, DateTime
```

я получаю такую таблицу
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А мне нужно из нее получить таблицу формата: "PValue3, PText5, Text1, Quantity"
должно выглядеть примерно так

37 Конвейер Т2.2 "Конвейер Т2.2" Авария сработал датчик "Подпора"! 2

37 Конвейер Т2.2  "Конвейер Т2.2" Авария нажата кнопка "Стоп"! 1

37 Конвейер Т2.2  "Конвейер Т2.2" "Конвейер Т2.2" Авария сработал датчик "Натяжения"! 1

единственное чего я пока смог добится это

```
SELECT  PText5, COUNT(MsgNr) AS Quantity
FROM [NEZHELSKYI-PC_HMI#3F9P_ALG_202206270821_202207061302].[dbo].[AlgViewExRUS_ID_OPT]
WHERE (Class = 64 OR (Class = 65 AND MsgNr = 210)) AND TimeDiff <> 0 AND DateTime >= '2022-06-30' AND DateTime <= '2022-08-06'
GROUP BY PText5
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но это не совсем что мне нужно.

Для уточнения:

PValue3 - это идентификатор механизма он уникальный для каждого

MsgNr - это идентификатор сообщения

Text1 - Составной текс сообщения (имя механизма + сообщение по номеру MsgNr)

Comment: GROUP BY + COUNT()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто добавь нужные столбцы и в SELECT и в GROUP BY:

```
SELECT  PValue3,
        PText5,
        Text1, 
        COUNT(*) AS Quantity
FROM [NEZHELSKYI-PC_HMI#3F9P_ALG_202206270821_202207061302].[dbo].[AlgViewExRUS_ID_OPT]
WHERE (Class = 64 OR (Class = 65 AND MsgNr = 210))
    AND TimeDiff <> 0
    AND DateTime BETWEEN '2022-06-30' AND '2022-08-06'
GROUP BY PValue3, PText5, Text1
```